# iOS 5 app with 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm writing an app that needs to target a minimum of iOS 5.

I've also written it so that it is compatible with the iPhone 5 4" screen.

I'm not 100% certain but I think I saw something around that said Apple will not allow apps to use the full 4" screen without being a minimum target of iOS 6.

i.e. if you target iOS 5 and your app uses the 4" screen then the app will be rejected.

Is this true? If so I'll have to decide what to sacrifice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this isnt true, you can set the minimum iOS version in the build settings to 5.0, and still support iphone 5 screens.

The sort-of-reverse is true, though. If the Base SDK isn't 6.0, then you can't use the iphone 5 screen size (which would be impossible anyway since no iphone5 can use < 6.0).

There are some sacrifices you have to make though, like you can't use autolayout if you also support ios5. You'll have to handle the varying screen size manually.

Comment: Ah, so I can target iOS5 with a base SDK of iOS6 as long as I make sure not to use anything that iOS5 doesn't know how to use. That's good as I've been doing that anyway (like, no autolayout, no literal dictionaries, etc...) Thanks.

Comment: Literal dictionaries should be ok, as that's a compiler thing, not the OS.

Comment: You can have a Deployment Target as far back as 4.3 and still support the 4" screens.